# When using MVVM, should I create new viewmodels to display the same model in different ways?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm

Lets say I have a dataset that I want to display in multiple ways. Maybe as a spreadsheet and a bar graph. The data in the model is identical for both views. Obviously the views must be different.

However, does it make more sense to create different viewmodels that wrap the same model, each handling the functionality specific to each view, or to have one viewmodel that exposes the model in multiple ways?

What if 90% of the functionality in each viewmodel is the same, with slight variations for differences in the corresponding view?

Is the viewmodel more coupled to the view, or the model?

Comment: You could do whatever is simpler. If they vary a lot, multiple ViewModels is probably the way to go, if you only need to combine a few small things, then just keep one view model with different views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's possible to give you a Yes/No answer.

It's really depends on your goals.

I don't see anything wrong in creating different `ViewModels`. If there are 90% of common functionality and you don't want to keep it in one `ViewModel` - just use an inheritance:

```
public class ParentViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    protected readonly Model _model;
    public ParentViewModel(Model model)
    {
       _model = model;
    }
}

public class ExtendedViewModel
{
    public ExtendedViewModel(Model model): base(model)
    {
    }   
}
```

This approach will help you to separate some View specific properties if you want so.

Also keep in mind that after you start adding new functionality to one of your Views you'll have to add new code to your ViewModels. As a result you'll get a ViewModel which has a lot of grid specific code as a chart specific. That will be a violation of [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

So my point is that you can use any of these approaches

- Use the same VM if your views need the same or almost the same amount of properties
- use inheritance if one VM's code is just a subset of another
- Use two different VMs if your views behave in a different way. Also, you still can keep common code in a base class.